# How does this obviously fake but convincing perpetual machine work?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Apparently, during a world fair (presumably Paris in 1889<sup>[Don't trust that fact]</sup>), an engineer showed a perpetual machine that could not be stopped. For months, he challenged visitors to stop it, but that machine always recovered the energy that people tried to take from it. Everyone was convinced it worked!

The "trick" was so simple: the action of trying to stop it would give the machine extra energy.

Now, I could have heard that from a highly unreliable source, but whether the story is true or not doesn't change my question:

What would that machine look like and how exactly would it work?

Comment: Unless the device is known, we can't really answer the question.  It would be all guesswork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible approaches - let's take a simple one; electrostatic. A static charge based [whirl](http://physics.kenyon.edu/EarlyApparatus/Static_Electricity/Electric_Whirl/Electric_Whirl.html) connected to a capacitor for storing more charge, and a fluffy carpet around. Stopping the whirl with your fingers charges it (and the capacitor) with new static charge picked through your feet from the carpet.